# List index out of bond 0

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
List<User> gmUser  = [Select Id, Name, Email,GM__c,IsGM__c,Division,Mapped_UserID_Name__c 
    from User where isActive=true and isGM__c = true and GM__c!=null];

sosTest.attachNoteAndUpdateLead(testLead[0], leadClashlist, true,gmUser);
sosTest.attachNoteAndUpdateLead(testLead[0], leadClashlist, false,null);
```

Comment: Debug log:= 09:49:46.404 (49404151439)|FATAL_ERROR|System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: Run this query, does it return anything ? Select Id, Name, Email,GM__c,IsGM__c,Division,Mapped_UserID_Name__c from User where isActive=true and isGM__c = true and GM__c!=null

Answer (score 3):

List index out of bounds: 0 means that one of your lists is empty, and you are attempting to access the first element in it.

I can see testLead, leadClashList and gmUser all as potential candidates.  But I would look at the testLead list object first.

Answer (score 1):

@user13298 More information (at least the error line or stacktrace) about your issue is helpful to answer the question. From what you have provided, we can say this.

Assuming the error in one of those two lines of code, the list reference `testLead` is initialized with empty list. It is equivalent to say,

```
List<String> values = new List();
values[0]; //This line would throw Array Index Out of Bounds exception
```

So make sure the reference `testLead` is initialized with at least one element before you could refer to it in those two lines.